# CSS multiple relative divs with absolutely positioned children

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm having some trouble creating a (somewhat strange) layout and I can't find an example anywhere of exactly what I'm trying to do.

I would like to layout multiple blocks that look like this:

```
 <div class="rel">
     <div class="item">--- a</div>
     <div class="item">- b</div>
     <div class="item">c</div>
 </div>
```

where all of the .item elements are on top of one another, but the .rel elements layout normally so they are all visible. It's important to note that all the .item elements within a .rel will be of exactly the same length, yet they may be of any length, so they might wrap onto a new line. Here is an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I've created [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/meredithmmyers/pen/QwwNyg/).

**SOLUTION**

In case anyone else finds themselves needing this truly strange layout:
[CodePen](http://codepen.io/meredithmmyers/pen/MYYmgE)

Comment: I have to wonder about the use case here.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but it seems that you want `<div class="item">` to display inline. you can use `float=left` or `display=inline-block` instead of absolute positioning. your divs are on top of each other right now .
Something similar to this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="rel clearfix">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
}
.rel {
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative; 
}
.item {
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  margin: .1em;
  float:left;
}
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

.rel-2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
  margin: .2em;
  position: relative; 
}
```

check it out here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEExvM

Comment: I made a change to this example and was able to achieve what I wanted. The example displays the .item elements _next_ to one another, and I wanted them _on top_ of one another (it's weird, I know). So I just changed .item { float: left} to .item {position: absolute} and it's working as desired. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use this on item

```
display: table-cell;
```

and this on rel

```
display: inline-block;
```

Have a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/h8rzw65p/

Total Code:

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.item {
  color: white;
  background: gray;
  margin: .1em;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
}    

.rel-2 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: steelblue;
  margin: .2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Or instead of table-cell you could do this on item:

```
float: left;
```

Comment: This is close, but since .item is a table-cell, the .item(s) were displaying next to one another instead of on top of one another like I was trying to accomplish. This was close though so thank you!

Comment: That's because your example was showing them next to eachother, since that's what it looked like you wanted.